# How to Detect New Lines Characters?

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, newline

I have a .txt file with the text split up in a number of lines. However, after I loop with C# all the characters via the following code

```
public static void printChars(string text)
{
    char[] myChars = text.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char ch in myChars)
    {
        System.Console.Write(ch + @" - \u" + ((int)ch).ToString("X4") + ", ");
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The issue is that I cannot see any new line characters (for example, u000A) or something since there are much text starting in new lines (for example u000D). How to detect that kind of unicode characters?

Comment: not that it matters to your problem, but you can iterate directly your `string text` variable, without creating a corresponding `char[]` calling `ToCharArray()`.
`foreach (char ch in text)` produce the same result of your code

Comment: *The issue is that I cannot see any new line characters or something* What does that mean? What isn't happening that you expect should happen? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need to get from your code. Are you trying to identify each kind of "new line" available in Unicode? if so, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode) can help

Comment: I expect to detect all hidden characters like "u000A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious explanation is that you wrote your code correctly and use StreamReader to read the text file.  Its ReadLine() method returns a line of text from the file **without** the line terminator.  Fairly important that it works that way, line terminators are not well standardized.

Not the only way it transforms the content of the file, its Encoding is important as well.  Another detail that is not well standardized, still lots of text files around that don't use utf-8.

If you want to see the raw bytes in the file then you must use FileStream.  And byte[] instead of string.